# UDP- Trouble reading bytes from socket in python?

Tags: python, arduino, network-programming, udp, serversocket

I'm trying to send 14bit sensor data from a microcontroller to a PC using UDP Protocol. When I send the data and receive it on the `package sender` application I am getting data in hex as expected.

[Energia Code:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyUBI.jpg)

[Python, `Package Sender` app screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9xeA.png)

Here, I am receiving it as char.

Sensor value in decimal: `(855) --- hex(357)` higher byte **03**, lower byte **57**. `57h` is char `W` in Ascii table

So when received through the socket, python outputs this as **03W**

How to receive in hex and convert it to decimal?
Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `struct` module to unpack it like this:

```
import struct
data = ['\x03W']
val = struct.unpack('>H', data[0])  # now an integer
```